# thyristor equation

Tags: power-electronics, scr, thyristor

I know how does an I-V curve of a thyristor look like, but is there any thyristor equation that can represent the curve?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each straight line can be characterised by an equation based on 2 transistors.

[image]

- The breakover or trigger voltage is the same as any power transistor, Vbe and current gain for trigger current,
- the foldback negative resistance depends on gm in two transistors and resulting saturation voltages plus 1 diode drop and Rs or ESR.
- The follow-on positive resistance depends on the power rating and junction size - the Rs or ESR is proportional to Pd power rating of the device. e.g. Rs=k/Pd where k is approximately = 1

  - ( the same applies to all diodes and LED's )  with a wide tolerance
- the reverse characteristics are likely similar to transistor PIV breakdown.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but since the thyristor has different operating conditions there is no single equation.

Like the JFET equation, in which you study differents equations before and after pich-off, in the case of the thyristor you should study the behavior when it is in blocking state, in on state and what happens when during the turn-on and turn-off process.